# Help me Understand What is Happening with my Transparency?

Tags: node-editor, transparency, shader-nodes

I need help understanding what is happening with my transparency of the object in these photos, below

[image]
[image]

Following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2cFVVotcs8), I'm trying to make a wood table with a glass piece in the center. However, when I look through the transparency, I can not see the object through it's own transparency. Is this just how the system works, and I need to make the transparent part a separate object? If i'm misunderstanding please let me know, I'm still new, especially to the node system and transparency system. Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach the blend file to your question to clarify some moments, please.
I can tell you in advance that it is better to have transparent objects as separate.

Comment: Hi :). There's no need to mix any shaders. For transparency use *Principled BSDF* Alpha slider. For a glass surface, use the Transmission slider :).

Comment: Glass is actually a transmissive material, this is a bit misunderstandable...  what you are doing by mixing in a _Transparency BSDF_ (and the same goes for using the _Alpha_ input on the _Principled BSDF_ as @JachymMichal suggested) is making those parts invisible for the camera. While a _Glass BSDF_ or the _Transmission_ setting in a _Principled BSDF_ also take the IOR into account and still have a reflective surface, the _Transparency_ or _Alpha_ simply make the material more or less visible depending on the greyscale value.

Comment: @YuriTitko sure thing! terribly sorry for the late reply, but this is the file with the table isolated https://file.io/OwRxpsjSJwSL

I'm working on trying to understand the other comments and try their suggestions as well, but until I get a better grasp on nodes atleast, I'll probably go ahead with making the transparent parts a separate object then

Comment: @Rez There is no texture in it) When you saving blend file you need to tick the box File > External Data > Automatically Pack into .blend. This will let you share the blend with texture.

Comment: oh dang, ok tho. "automcatically pack into .blend" is now checked, and the file is bigger! round 2!

https://www.file.io/YK9u/download/FXsQeSGkWXKi

Also it wont let me edit the comment, but thankyou for the replies!